# Static Analyzer for Configuration files

Tags: python, configuration-management, automated-testing

I'm currently planning to analyze csv-reports from our ActiveDirectory and configuration files from our switches with Python.
I'm thinking of having seperate modules for each type of data (csv, txt). But I would like to avoid writing much of the testing and reporting capabilities from scratch.

**Is there a python-module or tool, that can help me with this?**

Especially I'm looking for a solution to analyze generic text-files. Something to write rules like this: if there is this regex-match, there has to be this match before this match, otherwise report an error.

USE-Cases:
- Analyze switchconfig and report an error when a port is in a given vlan but has no mac-acl applied.
- Look for users in a csv where the Street attribute doesn't match the given string.

Comment: @HopelessN00b hoping this questions now fits this sites topic

Comment: Still seems kind of border-line, so the community may yet reclose it, but it's good enough to get rid of my mod close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 'analyze switchconfig...' case, you probably want NetConf to query, retrieve and present the networking information.  There's a very nice NetConf Python library made by Juniper called [PyEZ](https://techwiki.juniper.net/Automation_Scripting/010_Getting_Started_and_Reference/Junos_PyEZ)

For the second use-case, that just sounds like AWK, because it's very 'upon matching a pattern, execute action'.  If AWK is too arcane for you, there's [PyAWK](http://pyawk.sourceforge.net/) and [PAWK](https://github.com/alecthomas/pawk)
Not sure how nice they are, I have not tried them myself.  For stuff like that, I find native Python's regex more than sufficient.